# Using Try/Catch Inside a For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I've been trying to use a try/catch statement in place of multiple if statements in order to catch incorrect input from a user.  The divide by 0 catch is working as intended but the letter instead of number catch will not continue through the for loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Run1 {

public static final int its = 4;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numerator, denominator;

    System.out.println("Enter the numerator");
    numerator = keyboard.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < its; i++) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter the denominator ");
            denominator = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("numerator/denominator = " + numerator / denominator);

        } catch (java.lang.ArithmeticException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't divide by zero!");
            //i -= 1;
        } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
            System.err.println("Enter a number!");
            //i -= 1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

How come the loop speeds through when a letter is input as the denominator but not when the zero catch is thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your code throws `InputMismatchedException` the letter you entered has not been removed from the input stream. Your loop executes but it tries to read the same letter again (3 times total) and then exits since you have limited things to 4 iterations.

You need to discard the current input line after detecting an error.

```
    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.println("Enter a number!");
        keyboard.nextLine();
    }
```

This is why I dislike using scanners on an input stream.  My preference is to read the entire line into a buffer and then handle it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `denominator = keyboard.nextLine();`  instead of `denominator = keyboard.nextInt();`
 then convert String to integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Run1 {

    public static final int its = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numerator, denominator;
        String num, den;

        for (int i = 0; i < its; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter the numerator");
                num = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter the denominator ");
                den = keyboard.nextLine();
                numerator = Integer.parseInt(num);
                denominator = Integer.parseInt(den);
                System.out.println("numerator/denominator = " + (float)numerator / denominator);
            } catch (java.lang.ArithmeticException e) {
                System.err.println("Don't divide by zero!");
            } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
                System.err.println("Enter a number!");
            } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Enter a number!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```